# Display image loaded from sqlite blob in ReactNative

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This below is my implementation

```
return (
  <View key={page.ItemID} collapsable={false}>
    <Image
      style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
      source={{uri: URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(blobData, {type: "image/png"}))}}
    />
    <Text>Test</Text>
  </View>
);
```

An error occurred after running `npx react-native run-ios`, the detail here:
`undefined is not a function (near '...parts.map...')`

Answer (score 0):

I request, please check value you are giving as uri. you can come to know what is the problem.

checkout below link for the possible value of uri you can give as.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#source